# LPL 10.26 - Fitch - How to use ∀ Intro and ∃ Elim?

Tags: logic, fitch

I am using LPL (Language, Proof, and Logic, commonly known as LPL) and the bundled Fitch program. I am trying to solve problem 10.26:

```
10.26:     ∀x Tet(b) ↔ ∃w Tet(b)
```

Looks simple enough, as the null quantification means this is just:

```
Tet(b) ↔ Tet(b)
```

Which is, of course, a tautology. I do not need an premises for this. But my problem is that I do not know how to use ∀ Intro nor ∃ Elim as the book doesn't seem to cover these two, and I have no idea how else to prove the original statement without using those two.

So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I would like to add that I think "lpl" and "fitch" would be good new tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your concern : the exercise is proposed *before* the explanation of the *inference rules* for the quantifiers : thus, we are not requested to use them.

The exercise asks to prove that the biconditional : **∀x Tet(b) ↔ ∃w Tet(b)** is a *logical truth*, i.e. that

> the two sides of the biconditional are logically equivalent (2nd ed : 2011, page 286).

The definition of *logical equivalence* is :

> We say that two wffs with free variables are logically equivalent if, in
>   any possible circumstance, they are satified by the same objects. (page 278).

The discussion about *null quantication* (page 283) has showed that :

> if the variable **x** is not free in wff **P**, then we have the following
>   (logical) equivalences: **∀x P ⇔ P ⇔ ∃w P** (see page 82 for the symbol : **⇔** which stay for *logically equivalent*, and is **not** the *biconditional*).

This means that : **∃w Tet(b), ∀x Tet(b)** and **Tet(b)** are either all **true** or all **false**.

Consider the two cases :

*(i)* **Tet(b)** is **t** : then both **∃w Tet(b)** and **∀x Tet(b)** are **t**, and thus the *biconditional* : **∃w Tet(b) ↔ ∀x Tet(b)** is **t** (because : **t ↔ t** is **t**);

*(ii)* **Tet(b)** is **f** : then both **∃w Tet(b)** and **∀x Tet(b)** are **f**, and thus the *biconditional* : **∃w Tet(b) ↔ ∀x Tet(b)** is again **t** (because : **f ↔ f** is **t**).

Conclusion : in any possible circumstance, the formula **∃w Tet(b) ↔ ∀x Tet(b)** is satisfied, and thus it is a *logical truth*.

---

For a derivation with the *inference rules* of the book (i.e. with *Natural Deduction*) we consider only the case (the other one is similar):

> **∃w Tet(b) → ∀x Tet(b)**.

We have to "read carefully" the **Universal Introduction (∀ Intro)** rule (page 352) :

> if we have a derivation of **φ[c/x]** (i.e. the formula obtained from **φ(x)** replacing all occurrences of the *variable* **x** with the *term* **c**) and **c** does not occur in **φ** or in any undischarged assumption of the derivation, then we are licensed to derive **∀xφ**. In symbols : **φ[c/x] ⊢ ∀x φ**.

We have to note that the (meta-) expressions **φ(x,y)** neither means that the listed variables occur free nor that no other ones occur free.

1) **∃w Tet(b)** --- assumption [a]

start a subproof :

2) **Tet(b)** --- assumed for **∃ Elim** (page 357) : we introduce a new constant symbol, say **c**, replacing all the occurrences of **w** in **Tet(b)** with **c**, along with the assumption that the object denoted by **c** satisfies the formula **Tet(b)**; but there is no occurrences of **w** in **Tet(b)**, thus the result of **Tet(b)[c/w]** is **Tet(b)** itself.

3) **∀x Tet(b)** --- from 2) by **∀ Intro**

end of subproof;

4) **∀x Tet(b)** --- from 1) and the subproof above, by **∃ Elim**

> 5) **∃w Tet(b) → ∀x Tet(b)** --- from 1) and 4) by **→ Intro**, discharging the assumption [a].

Comment: Wow, thank you _very_ much for that detailed solution!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to 10.26. You will hit yourself for this, if you are as lost as I was!!

```
|_
|∀x Tet(b) ↔ ∃w  Tet(b)                                                             FO Con
```

Just type the same exact thing you see in question 10.26, then select "FO Con" without any premises.

This still doesn't answer the question about how to use ∀ Intro and ∃ Elim, but it answers how to solve 10.26. <s>I assume that ∀ Intro and ∃ Elim are covered later in the text, and I will update this answer when I come to that section.</s> See the very impressive answer above instead!

Comment: Of course, any other answers are welcome too!